# Select DropDown unable to change ColumnDataSource using JS Callback

Tags: python, bokeh

I have tried changing multiple parameters(arguments) but this doesn't work.

The bokeh version is 1.3.4.

```
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource, Slider, Select
from bokeh.plotting import Figure, output_notebook, show
import numpy as np
a = 20


bokeh_tools = "pan,wheel_zoom"

output_notebook()
plot_2s = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[1, 2, 3]))
plot_3s = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=[3, 4, 5], y=[1, 2, 3]))
line_source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[1, 2, 3]))

plot_1 = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", plot_width=800, tools=bokeh_tools, title="plot_1")
plot_1.line(x = 'x', y='y', source=plot_2s)
plot_2 = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", plot_width=800, tools=bokeh_tools, title="plot_2")
plot_2.line(x='x', y='y', source=line_source)

select = Select(title="SELECT", options=["val1", "val2"])
column = column(select, plot_2)
show(column)

select.callback = CustomJS(args={"cds2": plot_2s, "cds3": plot_3s, "ls": line_source}, code="""
         if(cb_obj.value === "val1"){ 
                 ls.data = cds2.data;
         }else if(cb_obj.value === "val2"){
                 ls.data = cds3.data;
         }
         ls.change.emit();
         """)
```

There are no error message the callback is not implemented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You callback is never executed, because it is never added to the output. As soon as you call `show` the HTML output is generated and displayed. Anything after that point is effectively a no-op, and does not exist as far as the output is concerned. Typically `show` should be called last.

Comment: Thanks. How do I debug to make sure that I can solve this on my own. Is there a way to see which element is assigned to a particular `column data source` ? Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I don't really understand the question, it has nothing to do with why the callback was not executing, which is simply that anything you actually want in the output has to happen *before* calling `show`. You are also already passing data sources to the glyph function calls above with the `source`. That specifies what data source the glyph uses. If you have a different question about data sources, then per SO practice, you should ask a new, different SO question.

Comment: Sure thanks . I was able to execute. I just had a different question.

Comment: Great! Definitey ask in a new SO topic for new questions. If this solved your problem it would be appreciated for you to accept the answer.

Comment: I have accepted the answer however I am low on reputation at the moment, SO doesn't record the same.

Comment: Ah, I did not know that! Thanks :)

Comment: You can help me by upvoting my question. This helps me get some reputation